# How can I automatically rename buffers created with `async-shell-command` to the shell command that was called?

Tags: shell-command, async

I am often opening exwm buffers by running `async-shell-command` but unfortunately these buffers always get named `*EXWM*`. It would be great if when I ran `async-shell-command 'firefox` the buffer that gets created would be named firefox.

Comment: I don't use EXWM, but `async-shell-command` accepts extra optional parameters. The second parameter is the name you want for the buffer with the results.

Comment: @darcamo: Please consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: please note that I am seeking a complete elisp function.

Answer (score 0):

something like this could work...

```lisp
(defun async-shell-to-buffer (cmd)
  (interactive "sCall command: ")
  (let ((output-buffer (generate-new-buffer (format "*async:%s*" cmd)))
        (error-buffer  (generate-new-buffer (format "*error:%s*" cmd))))
    (async-shell-command cmd output-buffer error-buffer)))
```

then it's possible to call `(async-shell-to-buffer "firefox")`

Comment: this behaves exactly the same for me as `async-shell-command`

Comment: in the `*Buffer List*` i get `*async:firefox*` and `*error:firefox*` so might be something else exwm is doing?

Comment: maybe try `rename-buffer` in a function advising `exwm-manage--manage-window` looks like that's where it's creating new buffers...

Comment: I'd copy this from the example config; it sets the name to a I'd expect (feel free to choose a different keybinding): https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm/blob/b62d5e79b0c1799f2cd941b4cec5bf8492cb322c/exwm-config.el#L52-L54